# Origem de expressões como "pé de laranja", "pé de manga", "pé de limão", etc

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

No registro informal da língua portuguesa, os nomes de plantas produtoras de frutas são frequentemente substituídos pela expressão "pé de [*nome da fruta*]".
Por exemplo,

- Laranjeira: pé de laranja
- Limoeiro: pé de limão
- Abacateiro: pé de abacate

Mas pensando bem sobre esse tipo de expressão idiomática, ele me parece realmente estranho. Qual o sentido da palavra *pé* nesse caso?

Como se originaram tais expressões? Qual é a lógica por trás delas (se há alguma)?

Comment: " esse tipo de expressão idiomática, ele me parece realmente estranho..."  Por esse motivo é que chamamos de expressão idiomática.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em latim *pes* (’pé’) já tinha significados relacionados. Diz [este dicionário de Lewis e Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpes) que o latim *pes* significava (tradução minha do inglês) “*a haste ou pedicelo* de um fruto, especialmente da uva”  e também “*a haste ou caule* da planta batis […] daí, como nome de várias plantas”; o dicionário dá o exemplo de Plínio, “pedes betacei”, literalmente ’pés de beterraba’.

Parece-me que a ideia que está por trás disto, é que o [pedicelo (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pedicelo/) sustenta o fruto. Aliás, a palavra corrente para isto em Portugal ainda é simplesmente *pé*, que também vem no [Michaelis (aceção 8)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/p%C3%A9/). No caso da planta batis, a ideia é ainda mais clara: o caule é a base da planta.

Saltando para o português, [Raphael Bluteau em 1720](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YfMwXg7LS3wC&pg=PA334&dq=%22arvore%20Arboris%20truncus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO37XOiMbkAhUjyYUKHfhvA3AQ6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=%22arvore%20Arboris%20truncus%22&f=false) diz que *pé de uma árvore* significa ’arboris truncus’, ou seja, o tronco. E o [Moraes Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=RA1-PA172&dq=%22hum%20p%C3%A9%20de%20oliveira%20de%20larangeira%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo1-OajcbkAhUPqxoKHccPBegQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22hum%20p%C3%A9%20de%20oliveira%20de%20larangeira%22&f=false) diz que é “a parte mais chegada á raiz” (tudo na grafia original) e também simplesmente “huma arvore, sobre tudo nova para se dispor” (ou seja, ’transplantar’) e dá como exemplo “pé de oliveira, de larangeira”.

Chamar *pé de oliveira* ou *pé de laranjeira* ao tronco junto à raiz compreende-se bem. Chamá-lo à arvore nova para transplantar, também, especialmente se pensarmos que essas árvores são por vezes pouco mais que um tronquinho; quando não são simplesmente uma [*estaca* (Michaelis 6)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/estaca/) que se crava no solo (ou se enxerta numa raiz). Daí a *pé de laranjeira* passar a designar a árvore já crescida é um pulinho; e daí para *pé de laranja* é uma simples simplificação. Nalguns casos pode ter sido uma questão de eufonia: *pé de abacate* é mais bem-sonante e fácil de dizer que *abacateiro* ou *pé de abacateiro*. Noutros ajuda a clarificar, como no caso de *maracujá*, em que a mesma palavra designa quer a planta quer o fruto.

Creio que *pé de laranja, pé de abacate*, etc. terá sido um desenvolvimento brasileiro. Aqui em Portugal, não me lembro e ouvir chamar isto à árvore (exceto n’*O meu pé de laranja lima*, que é de um autor brasileiro); e se ouvisse *pé de laranja*, a menos que o contexto esclarecesse, pensaria que era o pedicelo da laranja.

Comment: Interessante. Em francês, se diz "pied de tomate" (pé de tomate), mas essa expressão não funciona com outras plantas. Por exemplo, "pied d'orange" (pé de laranja) não existe. E em italiano, essa expressão não funciona sequer com tomates. Enfim, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @Hilder, muito interessante. Olha só [pied no Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pied/60776?q=pied#60391): "Partie d'un végétal qui est le plus près de la terre : Le pied d'un arbre"; "Plant de certains végétaux cultivés : Un pied de salade". A questão é que em francês, *tomate* é também a planta inteira. Portanto isto é exatamente como em português, exceto no *pé de laranja*, etc. Eu não referi na resposta, mas também se diz *pé de couve, pé de salsa*, etc.

Comment: No Brasil usamos as duas formas, dependendo de quem fala e para quem fala.  "Pé de..." é informal e por vezes soa caipira.  Por exemplo, dizer "um pé de uvas" ou "um pé de amendoas"  dá a impressão que a pessoa não conhece as palavras "videira/parreira" e "amendoeira".

Comment: "... pé de abacate é mais bem-sonante e fácil de dizer que abacateiro ou pé de abacateiro."   Creio que ninguém diria pé-de-abacateiro.  Seria um pleonasmo.

Comment: @Centaurus, comparei *pé-de-abacate* com *pé-de-abacateiro* porque *pé-de-abacateiro* segue o modelo mais antigo: pleonasmo ou não, há registo de *pé de laranjeira* muito antes de *pé-de-laranja* e o mesmo para outras árvores. Encontras estes pés plonásticos nos melhores escritores. E encontras muitos *pés de abacateiro* na net.

Comment: A minha conjetura, é que *pé-de-[planta]* se disse primeiro da que é plantada (pode ser uma estaca no caso da árvore), e que daí evoluiu mesmo para a planta crescida. Na minha memória, quando eu era criança, falava-se de *pés-de-couve* sobretudo quando as plantávamos.

Comment: Pé-de-couve também já ouvi por aqui, principalmente na expressão: tão sujo que dá pra plantar um pé-de-couve.  (teus pés estão tão sujos que dá pra plantar um pé-de-couve).  Como nunca tive contato direto com agricultores do ramo hortifrutigranjeiro, não sei qual o termo usado por eles.

Comment: O *c* de conjectura caiu com o acordo ortográfico ?

Comment: @Centaurus, em Portugal caiu, porque não é pronunciado.